# ¿Cómo mostrar el nombre del campo involucrado en un error de clave duplicada en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Mi objetivo es personalizar los mensajes de error que muestra MySQL (en este caso, el de clave duplicada). Cuando se intenta introducir un valor que ya existe en un campo identificado como `UNIQUE KEY` o `PRIMARY KEY`, lógicamente se mostrará un error que involucra a dicho campo. Capturo el código del error mediante pdo_mysql en PHP y muestro mi mensaje personalizado correspondiente. Lo que quiero es incluir el nombre de dicho campo involucrado en el mensaje. Quisiera hacerlo por PDO PHP, pero también admito hacerlo directamente desde MySQL. En caso de MySQL, los mensajes se almacenan en un archivo, pero quiero dejar ese archivo intacto. Quiero hacer esto desde mi código.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el mensaje de error por índice repetido en MySql, viene el nombre del índice, o PRIMARY si es el primario. Para para obtener el nombre exacto del campo o campos que forman parte del índice, tendrás que consultar la estructura de la tabla para obtener el campo o campos que lo conforman.

Eso lo puedes hacer con una consulta como esta:

```
SHOW keys FROM `nombre_tabla` WHERE Key_name = 'nombre_indice';
```

Donde `nombre_tabla`es el nombre de la tabla y `nombre_indice` el nombre del índice (o PRIMARY si es el primario).

De los registros obtenidos con esa consulta, tomas el dato Column_name, y ya tienes el nombre del campo o campos que conforman el índice.

Nota: Seguramente haya una forma de consultar obteniendo directamente los nombres de los campos, consultando contra el INFORMATION_SCHEMA
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Gracias por responder. Yo tengo una tabla que registra nombres de usuarios y direcciones de correos. También tengo un campo ID auto_increment que no me preocupa involucrarlo en esta pregunta (no hace falta). Tanto en nombre de usuario como el correo son claves únicas. Yo pudiera hacer una consulta que me diga si el valor a introcucir ya existe o no, pero quiero evitar hacer consultas adicionales. Serían 3: una para verificar si el nombre de usuario existe, otra para el correo y la última que es la que inserta los datos. Quiero concentrarlo todo en una única consulta.

Comment: Tanto el nombre de usuario como el correo pueden fallar debido a un posible duplicado. Lo que quiero es identificar cuál es la que falló (puede fallar una o ambas).

Comment: Quiero incluso llevar esto un poco más lejos agregando dos o más campos a una sola clave única (yo sé hacer esto). Ejemplo: Una tabla que almacenes letras y números (para nada es un ejemplo de la vida real), donde existan los pares A-1, B-2 y C-25. Pudiera introducir sin problemas el par A-2 o A-3 ya que aunque se repitan las letras o los números, no se repite el par como tal. Si introduzco nuevamente el par A-1 da error de duplicado. No se si es posible identificar más de un campo como en el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Como te decía, cuando falla una consulta de inserción por índice repetido, el mensaje de error incluye el nombre del índice (o PRIMARY, si es el primario). Entonces, sabiendo el nombre del índice, ya sabes qué campo ha fallado (en caso de índices formados por un solo campo), ya sea porque lo deduces tú mismo (te sabes la estructura de memoria), porque lo tienes registrado de alguna manera en el programa, o porque haces la consulta que te he puesto en la respuesta. No sé (o no entiendo) qué más te hace falta.

Comment: Ya logré hacerlo. Muchas gracias. Me sirvió.

Comment: Al final era algo obvio. Ya el propio error predeterminado de MySQL me daba la respuesta. Y como es un string incluso se puede extraer el nombre del campo. Tanto el campo como el valor duplicado aparecen en el error encerrados en comillas simples.